# Bubble-chart in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, bubble-chart

Using Neo4j I would like to plot Neo4j nodes with a different size in a graph with X- and y-axes, like an Excel bubble-chart.

[image]

Example data;

1. label = '1A', node diameter = big, x=5, y=3
2. label = '1B', node diameter = small, x=5, y=1
3. Label = '2A', node diameter = big, x=4, y=5
4. Label = '2B', node diameter = small, x=2, y=1

How could I represent these data in a Neo4j graph?

Regards,

Ralph

Answer (score 0):

As from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36534323 answer, I guess you can not change the size of a bubble programmatically or by data. So I guess you should try to look for a nother solution. Furthermore you may not persist the location of a bubble.

All in all, Neo4j is mainly for storing relation-based data, not for visualizing it, while it is still possible in a rudimentary manner.